# How can I fetch a single column value from database and then update this column value?

Tags: laravel

Please someone help me.How can I fetch a single column value from database and then update this column value?

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: Using query or programmatically?

Comment: @Nayanish using query.

Comment: Please can you describe your scenario properly

Answer (score 2):

let's say you want to update the name of the id 1 from the names table .Here Name is the name of model and 'name' is the column inside it. You can use pluck method to fetch a particular column from a table.

```
$user = Name::where('id' , $id)->pluck('name');
$previous_name = $user->name;
$user->name = 'New Value';
$user->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

Retrieve using Query Builder:

```
DB::table('table_name')->select('name');
```

Update:

```
Model::where('id', $id)->update(array('field_name' => 'value'));
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the OP question.

Comment: Updated answer. @hmrneves